# Deleting Empty Directories in Batch with Exceptions

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I recently started creating some small batch files, as I think that Batch in itself is interesting, but also because it helps automate some things that I do on a regular basis.

The script that I'm working on is a program that deletes all directories in a folder (As of now put in as the %UserProfile%), and allows all entires in an Exception file to be ignored. I don't want Exact Paths, I wanted it so that if the exception was present anywhere in the folders path, then it needs to be excluded.

Here's what I have (Keep in mind I'm not very good):

```
@ECHO OFF

CD %UserProfile%

SET /A Violation=0
SET "ExceptionFile=%*"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SHIFT
ECHO Starting...

ECHO Scan started at %TIME% > "%UserProfile%\Log.txt"
FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%D in (`"dir /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) DO CALL :DIREXPANDER "%%D"
ECHO Scan Finished at %TIME% >> "%UserProfile%\Log.txt"
GOTO:EOF

:DIREXPANDER
    SET /A Violation=0
    SET Directory=%1
    ECHO %Directory%
    FOR /F %%X IN (%ExceptionFile%) DO (
        SET "Exception=%%X"
        ECHO %Directory% Compared to %Directory:!Exception!=% >>  "%UserProfile%\Test.txt"
        If NOT %Directory%==%Directory:!Exception!=% (
            ECHO EXCEPTION: %Directory% Violates !Exception! >> "%UserProfile%\Log.txt"
            REM SET /A Violation=1
        )
    )

    IF %Violation%==0 (
        RMDIR %Directory% 2>NUL && ECHO DELETION: %Directory% >> "%UserProfile%\Log.txt"
    )
    GOTO:EOF
```

If I replace !Exception! With an actual String, it works just fine--but when using a variable it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any suggestions or issues that you notice!

Comment: You could simplify this greatly by using the `FINDSTR` command.  The `FINDSTR` command can use your exception file as input.  Then all you need to do is check the errorlevel of the `FINDSTR` command.

Comment: @Squashman I did have that, and it did work. The only issue is that FINDSTR is painfully slow, and the whole point of this is to be very fast, potentially scanning an entire drive

Comment: You cannot have speed in batch, just slow or very slow depending on what you are doing. You are using the wrong technology. The command prompt, before the mouse, was to operate a computer. To start programs and copy a file or two. It works textually while EVERY other Windows' language gets compiled somehow.

Comment: @CatCat I'm aware, but I was wondering if the program could work in it's current situation, as manipulating the string is easier and currently is possible with static strings.

Comment: How big is your exception file?  I find it hard to believe it would be slower then making a call to a function and then parsing each individual line of the exception file and then doing a substring to see if it is in the exception file.

Comment: Essentially to fix your code: `If NOT %Directory%==!Directory:%%X=!`

Comment: @Squashman The file isn't large at all. The only thing in it is Windows, as I don't want to delete important system directories. The slowness comes from using FINDSTR as opposed to the string manipulation.

Comment: @Squashman Also thank you for the fix, It worked perfectly!

Comment: I hope you realize your code will fail on directories with spaces and special characters. And if you wanted it faster you wouldn't make a CALL to a function.

Comment: @Squashman It does work with Directories with spaces. My Username contains a space, and I've tested it on the User directory.

Comment: @Squashman Also, I I were to not use the CALL function, it messes up the comparison, as it would change from being %DIrectories% to !Directories! because it wouldn't be passing it to the label.

Comment: Just tested your code versus using `FINDSTR` in the main `FOR` command.  I ran it against my user profile directory.  Your code took 12 seconds.  Using FINDSTR in the main FOR command. took 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you can write this without using the CALL to the Label.

```
@ECHO OFF

CD %UserProfile%

SET "ExceptionFile=%*"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SHIFT
ECHO Starting...

ECHO Scan started at %TIME% > "%UserProfile%\Log.txt"
FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%D in (`"dir /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) DO (
    SET "Violation=0"
    SET "Directory=%%D"
    ECHO %%D
    FOR /F %%X IN (%ExceptionFile%) DO (
        ECHO %%D Compared to !Directory:%%X=! >>  "%UserProfile%\Test.txt"
        If NOT "%%D"=="!Directory:%%X=!" (
            ECHO EXCEPTION: %%D Violates %%X >> "%UserProfile%\Log.txt"
            SET "Violation=1"
        )
    )
    IF "!Violation!"=="0" (
        RMDIR "%%D" 2>NUL && ECHO DELETION: %%D >> "%UserProfile%\Log.txt"
    )
)

ECHO Scan Finished at %TIME% >> "%UserProfile%\Log.txt"
```

This nested code was 5 seconds faster on my computer.